# How do I add an IPv6 address to Google API Credentials?

Tags: api, google-api, ipv6, google-api-ruby-client

I have a Ruby app in development that uses the Google API (custom search engine). It's been working great with the Public API access key.

I just upgraded my internet to Uverse and suddently the Google API stopped working. I figured out the issue was the IP address. My Uverse modem uses IPv6.

Unfortunately, Google Developer Public API access keys seem to only accept IPv4 addresses so when I try to add my IPv6 address I get the error message: "The IP address is invalid".

Has anyone been able to get this to work? I would prefer not to implement oAuth if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there is a bug with the new Google Developers console. By switching back to the original console, you can edit the allowable IP's and include IPv6 addresses.

Comment: This is the address of the old Google Developers Console: https://appengine.google.com/ Unfortunately I can't find the 'credentials' option anywhere in the old console...

Comment: I’m getting really tired of Google’s lack of quality control, in addition to their killing off or letting stagnate products I love. But anyway, thanks for the tip, worked like a charm!